# Role user and admin not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have i little problem in my roles, if i made login need show my name in bar menu, this work fine if i not use roles, but when i try use my roles check not work anymore. sorry my bad english

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


    }




    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
    {
        // Check if user is logged in
        if (User == null) { return; }

        // Get username
        string username = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        // Declare array of roles
        string[] roles = null;

        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            // Populate roles
            UsuarioDTO dto = db.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == username);

            roles = db.RegraUsuario.Where(x => x.UsuarioId == dto.Id).Select(x => x.Regra.Nome).ToArray();
        }

        // Build IPrincipal object
        IIdentity userIdentity = new GenericIdentity(username);
        IPrincipal newUserObj = new GenericPrincipal(userIdentity, roles);

        // Update Context.User
        Context.User = newUserObj;
    }
```

And in my Loyout.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @Html.Action("PaginaMenupartial", "Paginas")
                @if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    //if user is loged show logout
                    <li><a href="/conta/logout">Sair</a></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ViewBag.Tile == "Login")
                    {
                        <li class="active"><a href="/conta/login">Entrar</a></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {   //if user is not loged show login
                        <li><a href="/conta/login">Entrar</a></li>
                    }

                }
                // in this line below is my problem
                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("User"))
                {
                    <li>@Html.Action("UsuarioNavPartial","Conta", new { area=""})</li>
                }

            </ul>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pldbt.png)

if i remove and leave only   @if (Request.IsAuthenticated ) then work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAl3A.png)
 But i add   @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("User")) not work, i check in all code and seems fine, some one can help me?

Comment: we'll need a bit more detail of the problem than simply "doesn't work". What goes wrong, exactly? What debugging have you done?

Comment: when i try check role if user is admin or user  User.IsInRole("User")). seems this not check corretly then i get error

Comment: What is the error? Please be specific. Detail is important. The error could be anything, we don't want to guess.

Comment: nahh is my mistake, in my db roles names had space, jesus christ kkk

Comment: So you don't have a problem any more? If so you can delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the exact role is assigned to this specific user in the Database.
It has to be written exactly the same way.

I would also like to suggest, that you might want to use ENUMs or CONSTANTS as role names / symbols.
This way, a typo will not break a specific page (in case there is a typo again).

That wil ensure, that the role name is accessible and the same across the entire project.

I am assuming, that you will want to change roles later on or add / update.
This will also help with future development.